# write.csv permisson shiny server - R

Tags: r, shiny

I can't seem to use write.csv on shiny server. I get this error:

```
cannot open file 'data/Available.csv': Permission denied
```

I have read this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/srWETT6uL-I) and as a result tried this:

```
sudo chown shiny:shiny /path_to_app/data
```

But still no luck. I am using the following function from Dean Attali's post (http://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/):

```
outputDir <- "data"

saveData <- function(data) {
  # Write the file to the local system
  write.csv(
    x = data,
    file = file.path(outputDir, "Available.csv") 

  )
}
```

In combination with:

```
observeEvent(input$swafer, {

    saveData(values1$available)

  })
```

... to write my .csv file. Perhaps I need to be logged in as admin on the server to allocate permission (currently logged in as user)? Or does my `outputDir` perhaps have to be the full extension?

**EDIT**

It seems if I change the `outputDir` to anything other than `data` it works. I guess `data` is a special sub-directory in shiny.