# Write permission from shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

This is a follow up question to this ([write.csv permisson shiny server - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397327/write-csv-permisson-shiny-server-r)).

I am using a shiny app to search and save some data. I was having problems getting folder permission. After reading this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/srWETT6uL-I) I managed to solve by running this is RStudio server shell:

sudo chown shiny:shiny /path_to_app/path_to_data

However, this doesn't seem to work for me anymore. When I click my save data button in my app, I get the familiar error:

```
cannot open compressed file 'mutec/mutec_data.rds', probable reason 'Permission denied
```

So I read this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/528411/how-do-you-view-file-permissions) to try and find out the folder permissions. I get this:

Mutec_data$ ls -l ./mutec
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pdowns pdowns 446 Apr 17 12:22 mutec_data.rds

I'm struggling to interpret this. Does it mean that user pdowns can read and write? Should there be a "shiny" user with read and write permission?

This is my saveData function:

```
outputDir <- "mutec"

saveData <- function(data) {
  # Write the file to the local system
  saveRDS(
    object = data,
    file = file.path(outputDir, "mutec_data.rds") 

  )
}
```

Update

When I check the permissions of a folder that does let me write, I get this:

PPL040_baseline$ ls -l ./ctest
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 shiny shiny 105 Apr  8 06:45 Consumed.csv

Which must mean I didn't get this bit correct:

sudo chown shiny:shiny ...

Comment: You should probably use `chown -R` to recursively chown all subfolders.

Comment: Yes that is all I needed, thank you. I'm not sure why I didn't need to do this previously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to confirm for anyone who isn't familiar with Ubuntu, if this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/srWETT6uL-I) doesn't work for you then add `-R` after `chown` to change the folder permission. Thanks @warmoverflow.

Thanks Bastian for clarifying the full code snippet:

sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /path_to_app/

Run this in the terminal not the R console. Make sure you have sudo privileges and know your password.

Comment: Just to clarify the answer, in order to allow a Shiny app to write files to your local disk, i.e., you need to give the shiny user permissions over said folder with the following command: `sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /path_to_app/`